# PHP variable that contains a shell command or Linux tool

Tags: php, html

I have a page on a website that grabs a visitor's IP address and emails to an email account. My goal is to use a tool, GeoIP lookup, to associate the IP address with a city in the email content. What I want is to add the following command to the email content: `geoiplookup $remoteIpAddress`, but my attempts aren't working. I'm hoping somebody familiar with PHP can point me in the right direction. Here is the code that is currently working:

```php
<?php
include('session.php');
$yourEmailAddress = "user@example.com";
$emailSubject = "Example Subject";
$remoteIpAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$emailContent = "Blah Blah Blah: ".$remoteIpAddress;

mail($yourEmailAddress, $emailSubject, $emailContent);
```

I tried setting the variable with `$city = exec("geoiplookup $remoteIpAddress");` and updating $emailContent to: `$emailContent = "Blah Blah Blah: ".$remoteIpAddress .$city;` but that didn't work. I tried a few other variations of that, trying to get it working with shell_exec, with and without quotations, and nothing has worked. Hoping somebody can point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: I would use a geolocation api with php for example `https://ipstack.com/` (free with limitations) in order to achieve your goal

Comment: Can you explain what did not work? The `mail()` function or string concatenation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to for example at [ipstack.com](https://ipstack.com/product) and get your ***free API key***.

Then using the following function and your newly generated API Access Key for the service you can achieve your goals. The service will give you a stdClass object as a response with multiple properties, e.g.: city.

```
function lookup($ipAddresses, $token)
{
    $userAgent = ' PHP/' . PHP_VERSION . ' CURL/' . curl_version()['version'];
    $curl = curl_init();
    $url = 'http://api.ipstack.com/' . implode(',', $ipAddresses) . '?access_key=' . $token;

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return json_decode($response);
}
```

then

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$response = lookup([$ip], 'Your API Access Key comes here');
$city = $response->city;

var_dump($response, $city);
```

Comment: @rdarellano This is the better answer. You should use this, instead of mine, unless there is a specific reason you do not want to make remote calls like this. And I really doubt this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is indeed what @marcell suggested and use some remote API for this. But if you really want to do it with a command, something like this should do the trick:

```
$geolookup = `geoiplookup {$remoteIpAddress}`;
```

> Please note, that I am using ( ` ) and not ( ' )!